# In the Final Battle, when you remove doom tokens for rolling successes against an Ancient One do you stop counting successes for that roll?

Tags: arkham-horror

In Arkham Horror you have to roll a cumulative number of successes equal to the number of players to knock off a doom token from the Elder God's health. If you reach the number of players worth of successes do you then stop counting for the player and move on or do you count the extra successes against the next doom token?

We played it so that you kept on adding them but it meant that we turned Nyalothotep into mince meat quite quickly (One Character was blessed had a fight of 6 a shotgun and Fight +1 skill card though)

Comment: You did it correctly. Nyarlathotep is one of the easier ones to beat in combat. With only a -4 modifier and not resistant or immune to physical weapons, most characters will have dice to roll against him. Combined with his attack that could possibly make you lose a single clue token, you generally have an easy final battle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Just Read the FAQ:

**Q: In combat with an Ancient One, how do cumulative 
successes in the “Investigators Attack” step work?**

**A:** To defeat the Ancient One, the players must do a total 
number of successes equal to the number of players multiplied by the number of doom tokens on the Ancient One.

So, if 4 players are facing Yig (doom track of 10), they 
need 40 successes to win. For every 4 successes they do, 
they remove 1 doom token to track their progress. If the 
investigators get 9 successes in the first round of combat, 
they would remove 2 doom tokens, and 1 success would 
carry over to the next round of combat.

Comment: Fortunately there's no shortage of other counters you can use to keep track of the number of saved up successes (or the fraction of a doom token that's left, if you prefer).

Comment: Yeah we just used money tokens to keep track and reset it when we knocked off a doom token.